# Как ограничить длину строки при компиляции под Android?

Tags: android, delphi, строки

```
S: String[50];
```

Компилирую под Win32/64 все нормально. При компиляции под Android - ошибка:

> E2029 ';' expected but '[' found.

Есть другие варианты ограничить строку для использования в типизированном файле?

Comment: Не используйте типизированные файлы, уйдите уже от этого наследия турбопаскаля. Есть XML, JSON, да тот же SQLite (не совсем формат, но туда же), вполне уживающиеся на любой платформе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String[50]` не поддерживается на мобильных платформах.

Можно конечно попробовать использовать массив

```
...
S: array [0..49] of Byte;
...
```

Детали можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985895/2546083). Также на [docwiki.embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop) неплохо описано как мигрировать код на мобильные платформы.